# Add "\\-" every "x" letters of a string vector

Tags: r, string, date, format

I have a date vector like this

```
date <- c("01jan2020", "04mar2020", "20dec2020")
```

and I want to **separate it with -** following the next **pattern** (after the first 2 digits and after the first 5 digits):

```
date_transform1 <- c("01-jan-2020", "04-mar-2020", "20-dec-2020")
```

Next I want to convert the first letter of the month into a **capital letter**:

```
date_transform2 <- c("01-Jan-2020", "04-Mar-2020", "20-Dec-2020")
```

Any clue?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `lubridate` and `format`

```
library(lubridate)
format(dmy(date), "%d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "01-Jan-2020" "04-Mar-2020" "20-Dec-2020"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach splitting your text chain into multiple components:

```
#Data
date <- c("01jan2020", "04mar2020", "20dec2020")
#Extract first element
x1 <- substr(gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", date),1,2)
#Extract second element
x2 <- substr(gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", date),nchar(gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", date))-3,
             nchar(gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", date)))
#Format month
x3 <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', date)
x3 <- paste(toupper(substr(x3, 1, 1)), substr(x3, 2, nchar(x3)), sep="")
#Now concatenate
xf <- paste0(x1,'-',x3,'-',x2)
```

Output:

```
[1] "01-Jan-2020" "04-Mar-2020" "20-Dec-2020"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `character` object to `Date` and change its format.

```
format(as.Date(date, "%d%b%Y"), "%d-%b-%Y")

# [1] "01-Jan-2020" "04-Mar-2020" "20-Dec-2020"
```

The first letters of months will be turned to capital ones. You can also use `dmy()` from `lubridate` or `anydate()` from `anytime` to parse `Date` objects.

```
format(lubridate::dmy(date), "%d-%b-%Y")
format(anytime::anydate(date), "%d-%b-%Y")
```

---

Another option with `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(date, "[a-z]+", function(x) sprintf("-%s-", str_to_title(x)))

# [1] "01-Jan-2020" "04-Mar-2020" "20-Dec-2020"
```

or

```
str_replace(date, "[a-z]+", function(x) str_pad(str_to_title(x), 5, "both", "-"))

# [1] "01-Jan-2020" "04-Mar-2020" "20-Dec-2020"
```

Comment: Super efficient. Thank you

Comment: You are correct that yours came first. However, I found the code of @akrun more intuitive and fits better in my code and with "dplyr" structure (at least that is my perception when I tried the two codes). Your contribution was very valuable for me and I really appreciate it. Thanks again